# GLSL-ES3(webGL2): how to test extensions from fragment shader?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, glsles, webgl2, webgl-extensions

In webGL1 it was possible to test the availability of a GLSL extension from a fragment shader using (for instance) `#ifdef GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod` .
It seems to no longer be working in webGL2 (=GLSL-ES3.0): Extensions are not the same, but for instance `#ifdef GL_EXT_color_buffer_float` seems false despite https://webglreport.com/?v=2 tells that the extension is there.
Or what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the extension whether or not it adds a flag to GLSL

`EXT_shader_texture_lod` is specifically an extension that effects GLSL. [It's spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_shader_texture_lod/) says it adds that macro

> The GLSL macro GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod is defined as 1.

`EXT_color_buffer_float` is not an extension that affects GLSL. [It's spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_color_buffer_float/) does not mention any GLSL macros. No change from WebGL1

Those flags though are mostly nonsense in WebGL anyway. You can trivially do your own string manipulation

```
const shaderTextureLodExt = gl.getExtension('EXT_shader_texture_lod');


const shader = `
#if ${shaderTextureLodExt ? 1 : 0}
   ... code if shader texture lod exists
#else
   ... code if shader texture lod does not exist
#endif

  ...
`;
```

Or a thousand other ways to manipulate shader strings.

Here's another

```
const colorBufferFloatExt = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float');

function replaceIfDefs(s) {
  return `
  ${colorBufferExtension ? '#define EXTENSION_color_buffer_float' : ''}
  ${s.replace(/GL_EXT_color_buffer_float/g 'EXTENSION_color_buffer_float')}
  `;
}
const shader = replaceIfDefs(`
#ifdef GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
   ...
#endif
   ...
`);
```

etc...

Also since there never was a `GL_EXT_color_buffer_float` even in OpenGL there isn't much point in calling the macro `GL_EXT_color_buffer_float`. In fact it would arguably be a bad idea because it would end up looking like an official specified macro even though it's not. Best to chose your own name that doesn't start with `GL_` .

Also consider that using `#ifdef` might not even be a good idea since you can just use string manipulation. For example

```
const colorBufferFloatExt = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float');

const snippet = colorBufferFloatExt
  ? `
      float decode_float(vec4 v) {
        return v;
      }
    `
  : `
      float decode_float(vec4 v) {
         vec4 bits = v * 255.0;
         float sign = mix(-1.0, 1.0, step(bits[3], 128.0));
         float expo = floor(mod(bits[3] + 0.1, 128.0)) * 2.0 +
                      floor((bits[2] + 0.1) / 128.0) - 127.0;
         float sig = bits[0] +
                     bits[1] * 256.0 +
                     floor(mod(bits[2] + 0.1, 128.0)) * 256.0 * 256.0;
         return sign * (1.0 + sig / 8388607.0) * pow(2.0, expo);
       }
   `;

const shader = `
precision highp float;

${snippet}

uniform sampler2D data;
uniform vec2 dataSize;

void main(
   vec4 d = texture2D(data, gl_FragCoord.xy / dataSize);
   vec4 v = decode_float(d) * 2.0;
   gl_FragColor = v;
}
`;


...etc...
```

Comment: thanks !
About string manipulation: there are various contexts where you can't, because the only thing that is exported multi-platform is the fragment shader itself (so it's the only place you can test system-dependent features, e.g. webGL1 vs 2 via  __VERSION__ ): typically in Shadertoy, Unity, MaterialZ, and various online or multiplatform tools.

Beside,  __VERSION__ and *_EXT_* are made available in shaders by the language for a reason ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you're not mis-understanding?  There is no macro `GL_EXT_color_buffer_float` period. It's not missing from WebGL. It doesn't exist and never has. Also `VERSION` is useless for conditional programming because it's required to be the first line of the shader. Therefore you can't make your shader do some kind of version check since you have to use string manipulation to set the version in the first line anyway.

Comment: __ VERSION__ : since I didn't know, I used it and it work ;-)
Anyway, I don't think it is supposed to be in the first line, while #version is.

Comment: GL_EXT_color_buffer_float: yes, you already explained in your main answer that this very GL_EXT_ did not exist, while others does. I first though every extension were supposed to be testable.

Comment: Yes, `#version` is supposed to be the first line which was my point (sorry if that wasn't clear). The point is you already have to do string manipulation to set that first line. If you're doing some string manipulation to set that first line you can do more string manipulation to set other lines.  Insert `#version 300 es\n#define EXT_color_buffer_float\n` instead of just `#version 300 es` as the simplest example

Comment: what I mentioned was not #version, but the define _ _ VERSION _ _ (sorry, I just see stackoverflow ates the double _ into bold mode ).  Also, please do read my 1st answer: there are various situations where you *can't* rely on the CPU side.